# Does $\exists f'(x_0)$ imply that $f$ is defined on $N(x_0, \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$?

Tags: real-analysis

We define the derivative at $x_0$ as,

> For $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$, and $x_0 \in (a,b)$
>
> $$f'(x_0) \overset{def}{=} \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$$

#### Question

So, we often use the expression $\exists f'(x_0)$, then

**does it imply that** $f$ is defined on $N(x_0, \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$?

Or is there any counterexample for this claim?

Comment: Yes, it does imply that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is differentiable  at some point $x_0$  then not only it is defined on some neighborhood of $x_0$, but the function is also continuous at that point.

The existence of

$$f'(x_0){=} \lim \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$$ implies that $$\lim _{x\to x_0} f(x) =  f(x_0)$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have seen in most calculus books that they assume this condition of $x_0$ being in the interior of your domain. So, technically we can only say that a function is differentiable if this function is defined in an open domain.

But in general, one can define (extend the definition of) a function to be differentiable in a set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ even if the set $K$ is not open. We say that a function $f:K\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable if there exists an open set $U$ containing $K$ and a (usual) differentiable function $F:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $F|_K=f$.